# как сохранить префаб на сцене Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Существует префаб и скрипт который создает этот префаб на сцене, возможно ли сохранить его не создавая заново каждый раз?

Comment: Возможно, поместить объект на сцене и менять необходимые свойства. _Вероятно это глупый ответ, пожалуйста уточните вопрос_

Comment: изначально объекта на сцене нет, он создается (из префаба) и потом после завершения игры должен остаться на сцене

Comment: Тогда создайте в [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) какое-нибудь значение `bool` вроде `objectCreated` и смотрите при запуске, создали ли вы этот объект в одном из прошлых запусков.

Comment: если вы создадите объект из префаба во время самой самой игры, то по ее завершению он удалится, а я хочу чтобы после завершения игры он остался на сцене\

Comment: К сожалению, не получится. После завершения игры самой сцены тоже не остаётся. _(вряд ли вы бы стали рассматривать вариант с перезаписью сборки - это крайне сложно)_

Comment: Я говорил, о том, что **при загрузке игры** поставить объект на сцену, если он там был в прошлый раз.

Comment: То есть создался обьект из скрипта, потом при загрузке игры проверяю был ли он, и что дальше как поставить то его? создать заново? да это и есть пока мой основной вариант, запоминать позиции и параметры а потом каждый раз пересоздавать

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, вы хотите создавать объект, а потом когда игру выключили и опять включили, хотите чтобы объект оставался там, где был, когда выключили игру.

Но зачем вам его сохранять и потом... что-то странное. Просто изменяйте координаты самого префаба, а при заходе в игру создавайте его

```
GameObject prefab;
GameObject current_object;

private void Awake () {
    Instantiate(prefab);
}

private void OnApplicationQuit() {
    prefab.transform.position = current_object.transform.position;
}
```

Таким же образом можно изменять что угодно в префабе, а потом просто создавать его.

Comment: Эта идея тоже приходила мне, но из одного префаба создается несколько обьектов с разными параметрами

Comment: Таким образом есть два варианта :

Comment: 1. запоминать положения и параметры обьектов и каждый раз их создавать

Comment: 2. ( не рационально) создать заранее много обьектов и просто менять позицию и параметры.

Comment: Когда писал ответ тоже было два запасных варианта: 1 как и у вас - запоминать. Но обратите внимание, что нужно запоминать три координаты, дл я чего трижды использовать PlayerPrefs. 2й вариант - программно из скрипта при выходе из приложения полностью сохранять сцену, чтобы потом она загрузилась (то есть не делать новую сцену, а просто обновлять эту). Но я к сожалению не знаю, как сохранить сцену из скрипта. Погуглите - может что найдете, но я ничего толкового не нашел